# How to learn kernel programming from the start?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have completed my graduation recently. And I have only basic knowledge in C. But I would like to work on the Linux Kernel, and customize it according to my needs. Not only customize I would also like to contribute my own ideas to Linux kernel.

But I am starting from 0 now! So please suggest me how tostart and where to start with !

Comment: Have you asked on the kernel mailing list? What investigation have you already done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27782191/220386

Answer (score 7):

How much searching have you done on your own so far? There is a book, called [Linux Kernel in a Nutshell](http://www.kroah.com/lkn/) and you should also check [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/). There is also documentation in the kernel source code, but you can also view it online [here](http://lxr.linux.no/).

You can also check [Linux Documentation Project Wiki](http://wiki.tldp.org/).

Comment: If anyone knows about any other resources, please write them down in comments and I'll add them to the list.